# How to read directory (nodejs) and send it to frontend (angularjs)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I'm trying to read directory that has some image files from Node.js and use the data in angularjs, but I'm not sure my readdir is correctly working.

Here's my server.js code

```
'use strict';
const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs');
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
const path = require('path');
const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;
const server = http.createServer(app);

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client')));

app.get('/api/loadAll', function(req, res) {
  fs.readdir(path.join(__dirname, '../client/assets'), function(err, imgs) {
    if (err) { throw err; }
    console.log('imgs', imgs);
    res.send(imgs);
  });
});

server.listen(port, function() {
  console.log('Listening on port ' + port);
});
```

And here's my angularjs factory which receives from '/api/loadAll'

```
'use strict';
angular.module('app.service', [])
.factory('Images', function($http) {
  var loadAll = function() {
    return $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: '/api/loadAll'
    })
    .then(function(res) {
      console.log('res', res);
      return res;
    });
  }

  return {
    loadAll: loadAll
  };
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Quick question before I post my answer: are you trying to send a file for the client to download on the machine, or are you just trying to get images to display on your site?

Comment: I want to simply display on my site.

Comment: Oh okay, that's much simpler. I'll write an answer quick

Comment: One more question, because as I look at this I don't see anything wrong: what is the error you are getting? I am assuming you're trying to get an array of filenames to send to the frontend and have Angular load load them. Are the images in this folder going to be changed dynamically?

Comment: The problem that I have was it does not log anything in terminal whenever I restart my server. Could that be a problem where I am not indicating my path correctly in readdir??

Comment: That is strange....I replicated your code in a local environment and it works perfectly fine for me. Are you for sure calling the factory function? Stick a console.log() as the first line in the `loadAll` function and see if that shows up.